# Implement CSV download using current filters and sort

Tags: csv, react-data-grid

I need to implement a download feature.  It will read the data in the react-data-grid (adazzle), respecting the current columns, filters and sort, and create an array json (or comma separated strings) I can then pass to the react-csv module.

I have a data structure populated from the backend but it is not filtered nor sorted.  I need to be able to ask the grid for it's data on a row-by-row basis.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Without code or some context, I can't answer with certainty...
You supply the rowGetter prop with the collection to display, or the method to get the rows to display...I'm thinking if you filtering, then most likely you've got some sort of mechanism supporting that... Either way, you can use this property's value somehow to get exactly what you see in the grid.
If you literally want to interrogate the grid, you could try adding a reference to the grid, and then see if you can ask it for the row data. I can't remember with certainty that I saw a rows prop in the grids available props via the ref, but I imagine you should be able to (**,)

```
...

handleExport = async => {
  const exportRows = rows;
  // const exportRows = getRows(initialRows, filters);
  // const exportRows = this.state.gridref.CurrentRows   DISCLAIMER:CurrentRows is just for giving the idea... check out the ref yourself to see if it's possible to get the rows via the grid refs props. 
 downloadCSV( exportRows )
}
...
<ReactDataGrid
      ref={input => {this.state.gridref = input}}
      columns={columns}
      rowGetter={i => rows[i]} // or maybe rowGetter={i => getRows(initialRows, filters)[i]}
      rowsCount={rows.length}
      onGridSort={(sortColumn, sortDirection) =>
        setRows(sortRows(initialRows, sortColumn, sortDirection))
      }
    />
```

I've only ever [set / initialised] the `this.state.gridRef` prop in my `constructor`, but I guess you could also [set / initialise] it in your `componentDidMount` as well...
initialise like this:
`this.state.gridRef = React.createRef()`